# Populate filter by union of years from 3 tables

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I have asp.net mvc2 app, and I'm using Linq2Sql (dbml). I have 3 tables:

AccountHeaders, AccountDocuments and AccountNumbers

All off them have 3 columns, (id(PK), accountID(FK) and accountdate (datetime)). I want to populate SelectList in my View (year filter) by union of years from these tables (group by year). How I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
ctx.AccountHeaders.GroupBy(x=>x.accountdate.Year).Select(x=>x.Key).Union(
  ctx.AccountDocuments.GroupBy(x=>x.accountdate.Year).Select(x=>x.Key)).Union(
     ctx.AccountNumbers.GroupBy(x=>x.accountdate.Year).Select(x=>x.Key));
```

If date column is nullable you'll need to alter it a bit. Also check what SQL it generates, it might be necessary to rephrase the query to get more optimal SQL code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have modified your solution just a little and it works. :)